# I am trying to install Steam on ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, steam

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4)
     unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
    E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt-get -f install` to install the unmet dependencies?

Comment: Yes I tried that, still got an error

Comment: Have you tried installing STEAM using the graphical Ubuntu Software Center?  I'm asking because I've seen situations where software installed that way appears to be less problematic than what might appear to be the same operation committed from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Try resolving the dependencies manually, i.e.

```
apt-get install libcheese7
apt-get install libcheese-gtk23
apt-get install libglapi-mesa
```

If that doesn't work, try using aptitude, as its dependency resolution is often more effective than apt-get

```
apt-get install aptitude && aptitude -f install <thing-it-failed-on>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having this problem. I think it is down to a steam bug. Even when i reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04. Hopefully they fix this soon. Does this solution work in the mean time?