# How to fix Steams unresolved/conflicting dependicies in Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, package-management, dependencies, steam

I understand that there are many threads all posting about this similar issue. They each have different resolutions, and each problem is slightly different, but all seem to revolve around library dependencies.

The Steam version from the Ubuntu Software Center and from the Steam Powered website are not the same from what I have seen. Threads have further confirmed this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2241926 as well as checking version locally.

Not that it really makes much of a difference. I've downloaded both Debian Packages and they seem to run into the same issue. Unresolved dependencies.

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages: 
    libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386
[sudo] password for [username]: 
.........................................................................................
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5)
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
Press return to continue:
```

Interestingly enough, one poster suggested to upgrade the distribution on a month old post: [Installing Steam on ubuntu 14.04 libc.so.6 error please help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671160/installing-steam-on-ubuntu-14-04-libc-so-6-error-please-help)

I'm not one to steer away from stable software and am using the latest LTS release. I've done recent releases before, and can't stand the instability and buggy-ness of it all, so to me... it doesn't make much sense to just jump into the deep end and say, "oh well. I might as well upgrade my distribution to the bleeding-edge." without a valid explanation; which is not provided.

I must say that this post was the most helpful so far: [I am trying to install Steam on ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/639931/i-am-trying-to-install-steam-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-64-bit)

It touched on something, rather unwittingly, that I didn't pick up on before hand. **These packages are already installed and yet Steam complains that they are not there.** When I ran `sudo apt-get install {dependent packages here}`, *Ubuntu complained that they were already installed*! Aptitude became useless at this point since I realized I can't resolve resolved dependencies redundantly (i could, but i don't really see the point).

That's when I bumped into the next thread: http://www.askubuntu.com/questions/588024/steam-install-error-on-14-04-ubuntu-64bit

This one piqued my interest because it meant that I should remove my current libraries and install the new ones, although I'm not sure if I should be using `trusty` instead of `utopic`, something to research. But it was labeled as a workaround (something I've yet to try my self).

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386
```

The last thread I found: http://www.askubuntu.com/questions/256271/how-do-i-install-steam-64-bit-when-package-dependencies-cannot-be-resolved

This one was interesting because it suggests to turn on support for i386 packages.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

I'm pretty sure this doesn't work seeing as I did give it whirl, but I would assume the i386 is supported unless the packages have been deprecated (which they were deprecated).

**Steps I took:**

- Fresh Install of Ubuntu LTS 14.04.3
- Ran updates during and after install
- Downloaded Debian Package from Steam directly
- Ran `dpkg` and then ran Steam
- Steam prompts for additional packages
- Typed in admin password (this step always fails!)
- press return for continue
- Then Steam ran an update and started right up

Every time I launch Steam, it prompts me for packages that come with Ubuntu by default (depending on how Ubuntu configures itself for your device(s)).

I noted that the `steam-launcher` differed from `steam` and would never actually execute the app. So when `steam` finally did run, I locked the icon to the launcher.

I have not come across a valid solution and none of the threads above seem to supply one either. If I happen to find a valid solution I will post, but until then, if anyone has any suggestions, please by all means... POST!

Update on Oct 3, 2016:
I never found a solution to this issue, but this post helps consolidate several similar or related issues. I did find out later on that 15.10 implemented official repositories from steam and that 15.04 <= used to have older repositories which are now deprecated. (You can always download the deb file, there's a link provided below in the comments thanks to @Organic Marble). I eventually decided to move from 14.04.1 to 15.10 and stayed there until 16.04.1 was released. Steam works fine and can be installed easily using the apt tool with 15.10 >= and up.

Comment: What's the output of `sudo apt-get install -f libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libc6:i386`?

Comment: what's askubuntu.biz?

Comment: sudo apt-get install -f probably will solve your issue, but nobody can't know without the errors shown in the terminal.

Comment: You can still get the .deb file from http://store.steampowered.com/about/, I just checked. The Install Steam Now button at the bottom of the page links to https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steam.deb

Comment: Cool, ill change it to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

Just open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install steam -y
```

That seems to fix all unmet dependencies. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To install steam, if you have issues, the best approach is to use the terminal with dpkg + apt. Those utilities will give you the most fine grained control. If you get problems you'll be able to copy/paste the errors to get more help.

This steps also work for Debian.

- Download the steam DEB package
- Enable the 32 bit repository: 
  `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
- Update the package list: `sudo apt-get update`
- Try to install the package with dpkg, it will fail because of the missing dependencies: `sudo dpkg -i steam.deb`
- Now, correct the missing dependencies: `sudo apt-get install -f`
- Verify that steam is properly installed: `sudo dpkg -i steam.deb`

At this moment steam should be installed.

There have been cases where the libraries in steam created issues, like: https://askubuntu.com/a/706796/430526

In other cases Steam will complain because the packages with the 32 bit 3D libraries are not installed, you may need to install those packages. For example if you use nvidia drivers: `install libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386`

An useful link regarding missing 32bit 3D drivers: https://www.codeweavers.com/support/wiki/Diag/MissingLibGL

If it doesn't work, paste the contents of your terminal, it is usually easy to see what the problem is from them.

Comment: The real issue is the cryptic message that you're missing dependencies and proprietary drivers while they are already installed. I had run dpkg and aptitude and utilized apt as well, but the issue seems now that there were conflicts in steams packaging because the steam-client is technically closed-source (I would nvr have known this back then)

Comment: The devil there is on the details. The errors are very descriptive, specially dpkg ones. The steam package being closed source shouldn't matter if it is properly created. The issue seems to be then a conflict with your drivers installation.